# arangodb: attribute value history

Tags: data-modeling, arangodb, revision-history

For certain nodes in our database we need to store a history of each changed field value.

We are considering two possible structures for this:

1. Using a key-value index, with entries of the form

   ```
   id.attribute_name.counter = {
       "field": "name",
       "old_value": "jon",
       "new_value": "john",
       "datetime_modified": "some-date",
       "modified_by": "some-user"
   }
   ```

   where `id` is the unique id of the record, and `counter` is just an incremented integer.
2. Using the graph structure, and having "delta" nodes connected to the main node, with a "modification" edge, and the same JSON object (+ the attribute name) stored in this node.

The history info will sometimes be used to decide whether or not to update a record with new info.

Would like to know pros/cons of both approaches.

Answer (score 5):

I think there is a third approach that you could use:

3. Create an "updates" collection, having documents of the following format:

   ```
   {
       reference: <_id of updated object>,
       attribute: <name of the updated attribute>,
       counter: <number>,
       old_value: ...,
       new_value: ...,
       date_modified: ...,
       modified_by: ...
   }
   ```

   with a combined hash index on reference and attribute.

This can hold all the updated information you require.

Why do I prefer this method:

- Has the drawback that you have to maintain the update counter for each attribute somewhere, as there is no `_id` prefix query (yet) in AQL. This would be required to get all updates for one attribute in a document.
- The graph structure does basically the same thing as my third approach does, however it creates unnecessary overhead by creating two indices you do not really need (`_from` and `_to`), you would only need one of them.
- This has the benefit above 1. that you can sort by counter and f.e. get the last 5 updates easily. Also you do not have to maintain the counter somewhere else or use "try-and-error" to find the latest update. Above 2. it has the benefit that it uses a combined index instead of the edge index, where one of the edge sides is not used.

Example AQL (assume that your records are stored in collection `records`:

```
FOR r IN records
    FILTER r.name == "super important"
    FOR update IN updates
        FILTER update.reference == r._id && update.attribute == "name"
        SORT update.counter DESC
        LIMIT 5
        RETURN update
```